# Adding a favicon - HTML

Tags: html

i know this may be a stupid question, but i am trying to add an icon to my website, and for some reason it isn't showing up. Ive tried putting the favicon.ico in the root folder, and it doesn't show, and i've also tried using the following pieces of code in HTML

```
<link rel = "shortcut icon" href = "images/icon.ico">

<link rel = "shortcut icon" type = "image/x-icon" href = "images/icon.ico">

<link rel = "icon" type = "image/png" href = "images/icon.png">
```

Obviously i have all the images, and i'm not trying to use a image that doesn't exist. At the moment i'm using chrome and i've tried with IE

Comment: Try the last example. Give the absolute link to your favicon file. Clear your cache and cookies. It should work :)

Comment: Try to name it `favicon.ico` and to put in your web root folder.

Comment: Not directly an answer to this, but I'd really get out of the habit of having whitespace between attribute name, assignment and value

Comment: @trollster This did not work :c

Comment: @Paul I've already tried this and it didn't work. I tried clearing my cache and all cookies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Favicons are heavily cached, and differently from temporary Internet files like images, so it may just be that the favicon got cached in the wrong way during initial loads. I would configure it how you would like it to work (probably just stick the favicon in the root folder of the site, you can override on specific pages) and only then open up the site/page on a totally new browser and bookmark the page.  The browser should be one that you haven't tested the site on before.

Comment: Thank you, I completely re-wiped the cache, tried it, didn't work, then i downloaded Firefox and it worked perfectly. I closed Google chrome and opened it up again and it now shows :) Thank you so much! I was already downloading firefox, that's why i got it so quick :)

Comment: Yeah, in my experience favicons aren't cached in the same way as other images. Sometimes to refresh the favicon you have to browse to it's URL directly.   In older versions of ie you used to actually have to favorite/bookmark a new site before it would hold onto the favicon, though that's never really been the case with ff & chrome. Overall just remember that your favicon may be set up to work fine if you test in a totally fresh browser, like one on someone else's computer.

Answer (score 0):

Now any browser find favicon.ico in your website root. Like http://example.com/favicon.ico and your no need to any code.

If this not work, download favicon.ico from any website and try with this icon.